# how to use merged array to d3 collapsable tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, merge

I'm working with a lot of small JSON files. The task is to represent it as a merged big json file to the d3 collapsible library. From resources on the  internet I have found a way to merge arrays by using the following script:

```
(function($){
  $.concat || $.extend({
    concat: function(b,c){
      var a=[];
      for(var x in arguments)
        if(typeof a == 'object') a = a.concat(arguments[x]);
      return a;
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

function foo() {
    $(function() {
        var a = $.getJSON("clinical.json");
        var b = $.getJSON("industry.json");
        $finalObj = $.concat(a, b);
    });
}
```

After I merged the files, I tried to set the result into the library

```
 treeJSON = d3.json(foo(), function (error, treeData) { ...
```

but I am getting the following errors:

```
1. GET http://localhost:63342/testMerg/undefined 404 (Not Found)
2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x0' of undefined
```

If the nature of the second one I clearly understand, it cause d3 doesn't have necessary resource that build a tree, so the first one I don't understand at all.

What I'm trying to get in the end, is to compare two JSON files, merge them into a single file and render it with d3.

I have tried to find some library on the internet for merging and comparing json files but, unfortunately, was unlucky... Can anybody give me an advice?

Comment: Function `foo()` doesn't return anything. This is the reason, why the call to this function evaluates to `undefined`, which is part of your GET request. This request consequently fails, resulting in error #2. `d3.json()` expects a path as its first argument.

Comment: For starters, `$.getJSON` is asyncronous. So both `a` and `b` are undefined at the time of `$.concat(a, b)`, in the snippet you're showing. Also, `d3.json()` expects a string url, not a function that returns data (which it doesn't, because of the reason described above). Maybe [d3 queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) is what you want for loading all those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` is asynchronous, `$finalObj` would not be set as concatenated arrays returned by `$.getJSON()` , but concatenated jQuery objects.

Try using `$.when()` to wait until both `$.getJSON()` calls complete before concatenating responses, `.then()` to perform process after asynchronous processes.

```
var res = [];

$.when($.getJSON(), $.getJSON())
.then(function(a, b) {
   res = $.concat(a[0], b[0]);
   return res
})
.then(function(data) {
  // do stuff with `data` : `res`
})
```

Comment: I used your code and have got this error 'Uncaught TypeError: $.concat is not a function'  after .then(function(data) I put return data;

Comment: @Anton Original Question does not appear to address usage or implementation of `$.concat()` ? Did not attempt to use the function. You should be able to substitute `$.merge(a[0], b[0])` for `$.concat()`

Comment: My fall, sorry, too tired after hard day... but it still shows me the second error

Comment: @Anton No worries. Does substituting `$.merge()` for `$.concat()` return expected results ?

Comment: unfortunately nope it returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x0' of undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105058/discussion-between-anton-and-guest271314).

Comment: @Anton Have a look at my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734212/how-to-use-merged-array-to-d3-collapsable-tree#comment59143282_35734212) on the question itself. Your call to `d3.json(foo()` is flawed. This is your first error causing the trouble you see. There might be more issues involving concurreny as were mentioned in the other comments, but you really need to fix this call.

Comment: @altocumulus yep I saw your comment, direct link to the file works well... so I'm trying to fix broken function